# How to write 128Int or 256Int to Buffer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, buffer, int128

I have a BigInt `170141183460469231731687303715884105728n` which is 128 bit integer, then i want to convert that integer to buffer.

But as i know, nodejs Buffer is doesn't support 128 or 256 bit integer, only 64 bit integer they supported.

So the question is, how to convert that integer to buffer? i have search in internet but i didn't find anything.

Sorry if my English is bad, thanks you for your answer.

Comment: You could convert the BigInt to a string of digits and store the string.  Then, you don't have to use a Buffer at all.  And, reading the data from the string will be simple also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix this issue, i do looping `16` times *(Buffer length of 128Int is `16`, 256Int is `32`)* then shift right with `8` *(Buffer length of 64Int)* `*` `index of looping` on the bigint and do `bitwise and` *(`&=`)* with `255` *(range max of buffer)*. Maybe someone found a better way than this.

```js
function int_128_to_bytes(int){
  const bytesArray = []; 
  for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
     let shift = int >> BigInt(8 * i)
     shift &= BigInt(255)
     bytesArray[i] = Number(String(shift))
  }
  return Buffer.from(bytesArray)
}

console.log(int_128_to_bytes(BigInt(2 ** 127 -1)).toString("hex") // 00000000000000000000000000000080
```